# how can I define custom document properties with chemistry in-memory and/or nuxeo?

Tags: cmis, opencmis, apache-chemistry, nuxeo

I'm very new to Open CMIS so I apologize if this is common knowledge. My documents need a custom property (i.e. a boolean "nm:test" or something like that) for my implementation. I've read on the web that I can do this with Alfresco via xml config/aspects. Could I perhaps do it with Chemistry In-Memory so I can test an application that's using CMIS to store documents and files? Could I also do it with Nuxeo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Nuxeo Platform doesn't implement CMIS 1.1 type mutability.

To create new types and properties in the Nuxeo Platform, you have two options:

- follow the documentation about [document types](http://doc.nuxeo.com/x/D4AO) to understand what they are and what XML to add,
- use the [Nuxeo Studio](http://www.nuxeo.com/products/studio/) service to do that in a few clicks.

Note that Nuxeo Studio has a free 1-month trial but is not a free service after that. However anything you've created during the trial with Nuxeo Studio can be used with no restrictions forever.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the CMIS workbench to create or modify type definitions. 
Open the workbench and connect to your repository. Press the button "Types" in the toolbar. You get a new dialog where you can save the currently selected type definition to a file. You can then modify this file in a text editor according to your needs. Afterwards you can press "Create Type" and load the edited file in the workbench and upload it to the repository.

This method should work with any CMIS 1.1 compliant repository having the TypeMutability capability.